# Symbolic tick in a pgfplot environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$E$}, yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty, axis lines=middle, xmax=1.2, ymax=1.2, legend pos=north west,
    %symbolic x coords={-A,A},
    %xmin = {-A},
    %xmax = {A},
    %xtickmax={2},
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=-1:1, 
    samples=100, color=red,
    dashed,
    ]
    {-x^2+1};
    \addlegendentry{$T(x)$}
    
    \addplot[
    domain=-1:1, 
    samples=100,
    ]
    {x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$U(x)$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I was trying to force the tick to be (-A,0) and (A,0) at the point (-1/sqrt(2),0) and (0,1/sqrt(2)). Could someone help me to achieve this?

[image: graph with a symbolic tick]

Comment: What doyou mean????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear if your problem is only xtick labels or you like to have reproduced showed image.  Assuming the first possibilities:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center, 
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$E$}, 
    ytick=\empty, 
    xtick = {-1,1},
    xticklabels={-A,A},
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick labels={0},    
    xmax=1.2, ymax=1.2, 
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=100,
    ]
    \addplot[color=red,dashed]  {-x^2+1};
    \addlegendentry{$T(x)$}

    \addplot[no marks] {x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$U(x)$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you assumed correctly. I needed a "xtick labels" represented by letter "A". I was considering that the solution would envolve symbolic coordinates, but in the manual it was used only with bar plots, i.e., with acquired data. Thank you so much and have a nice day!